# Linking Exception when calling C++ function from inside source object (.so) file in java using JNA.

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I am trying to access functions from a c++ .so file in java(JNA). I am able to call simple "Hello" type function from this .so file. But when I am trying to access other functions which internally calls functions from other files (.so file which is written in C), I am getting exception like: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/stpl/workspace/TestJNA/bin/libhello.so: undefined symbol: PInit

I am stuck in this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: well, .so should be short for shared object. and your title says JNA. and i think it's a good idea to paste some related code.

Comment: So what is it calling C or C++? These are different languages.

Comment: @JensGustedt- I am calling C++ function and that C++ function is calling functions from library that is in C.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr- I am creating .so from C++ code and then I am trying to access function from it using Java Native Access(In java application).

Answer (score 0):

Now my problem is solved.
In case anyone have the same problem, the problem was in .so file. 
Below is the script for .mk file to create .so file.

CC=g++ 
CFLAG= -g -O0

PRNINC=  -I ./Include -I ./PRT.IF -I./app
PRNLIBS= -lHWIGotPrinter -lcommon -lpthread  -ldl

ASTYLE=astyle
ASTYLEFLAGS= --style=ansi -t -p -b -S -K

compiledate=$(shell date '+%F %T')
DEFS=-D DEFINE_MKDATE="\"$(compiledate)\""

INC_PUB= -I./Include  -I./PRT.IF -I./SCANNER.IF -I ./Include
INCLUDE=$(INC_PUB)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAG) $(DEFS) -fPIC $(INCLUDE) -c $< -shared -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAG) $(DEFS) -fPIC $(INCLUDE) -c $< -shared -o $@

.PHONY:all
all:   PRN

## HSCAN CDU UPS

PRNAPPS=  bin/libprntest.so
PRN:   $(PRNAPPS)

bin/libprntest.so:  app/prn_proc.cpp  app/prntest.cpp  app/myCpp.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAG) $(DEFS) $(PRNINC) $(PRNLIBS) $^ -shared -o $@

dist: all
    mkdir -p insttest
    rm -rf insttest/*
    cp -a bin insttest/ 
    cp -f Makefile  inst/
    tar -czf inst-$(MAJOR).$(MINOR).tgz insttest/
    rm -rf insttest

install: 
    install -m 755 $(PRNAPPS)  /usr/bin

cleanbak:
    find . -name *.o    |xargs rm -f
    find . -name *~     |xargs rm -f
    find . -name *.bak  |xargs rm -f
    find . -name *.orig |xargs rm -f
    find . -name *.cpp  |xargs chmod 644
    find . -name *.h    |xargs chmod 644
    chmod 644 ./etc-lib/gotlib.*

clean:
    find . -name *.o    |xargs rm -f
    find . -name *~     |xargs rm -f
    find . -name *.bak  |xargs rm -f
    find . -name *.orig |xargs rm -f
    find . -name *.cpp  |xargs chmod 644
    find . -name *.h    |xargs chmod 644
    rm -f  $(PRNAPPS)  $(SCANAPPS)  $(HSCANAPPS)  $(UPSAPPS)  $(CDUAPPS)  $(HARDWAREAPPS) $(CMOSAPPS) $(TOOLSAPPS)

help:
    echo "make style "
    echo "make cleanbak"
    echo "make clean"
    echo "make"
    echo "make dist"
    echo "make install"